# Flutter - how to ignore parent touch event on child touch event?

Tags: flutter, listener, flutter-listview, flutter-onpressed

This should be pretty basic, but I can't seem to figure out how to disable or ignore parent touches when a child IconButton is pressed.  I am working on a treeview that can expand and collapse.  When I click the row (a Card), the children will be shown or not (which is working).  The problem I have is that when touching the child IconButton, both the IconButton's onPressed event as well as the Listener of the Card's onPointerDown event.  But I only want the IconButton's onPressed event to trigger.  Any suggestions?

[image: Here is the widget tree]

[image: A screen shot]

The listener for the card (row):

> ```
>     Listener(
>         behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
>         onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
>           toggleExpanded();
>           print("row pressed");
>           },
>         child: widget.parent
>     ),
> ```

The IconButton:

> ```
> return Card(
>   color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
>   elevation: 2.0,
>   child: ListTile(
>     leading: Icon(Icons.folder, color: Colors.amber),
>     title: titleWidget,
>     subtitle: countWidget,
>     //trailing: expandButton,
>     trailing:
>       IconButton(
>         icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () { print("more icon"); },
>       ),
>   ),
> );
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GestureDetector instead

```
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () { print("row pressed"); },
      child: <widget>
    ),
```

Comment: That's it.  I'm not sure why I switched from GestureDetector to Listener at some point, but going back to GestureDetector worked.  Thanks!