# Is there a way to distinguish between left and right mouse pan in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gesture

Is there a way in which I can distinguish between left button and right button panning in flutter?

I am using a GestureDetector with an onPanUpdate callback. However the details (`PanDown/Update/EndDetails`) of the function do not have details about the buttons that are being pressed (Thus used to pan).
One possible workaround I found is to cache the point using a Listener:

```
return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (event) => _cachedPointerDownEvent = event,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanDown: (details) {},
        onPanStart: (details) {},
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          switch(_cachedPointerDownEvent!.buttons){
            ...
          }
        },
        onPanEnd: (details) {},
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            ),
      ),
    );
```

However this is not too elegant and does not integrate well with other imput methods (trackpad,etc).

I also tried a Listener with the onPointerMove callbacks but the Listener always fires even when another listener  is visually in front of it ([Flutter - how to ignore parent touch event on child touch event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72099696/flutter-how-to-ignore-parent-touch-event-on-child-touch-event)).

Is there a way to have details about the pointer used for the drag or to have different event for different mouse buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the functionality by using a `RawGestureRecognizer` and configuring it as needed by your use case:

```
return RawGestureDetector(
  gestures: {
    /// The type of gesture recognizer to add.
    PanGestureRecognizer:
        GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<PanGestureRecognizer>(
      () => PanGestureRecognizer(
        /// Change this condition to match the buttons you want to allow.
        allowedButtonsFilter: (buttons) => buttons == kSecondaryButton,
      ),
      (instance) {
        /// Add your event handlers here.
        instance
          ..onDown = (details) {
            log("onDown: $details");
          }
          ..onUpdate = (details) {
            log("onUpdate: $details");
          };
      },
    ),
  },
  child: YourWidget(),
);
```